CTCs stability before and after cultivation, what to look for?
I want to cultivate CTCs filtered out from the patients with... say metastatic breast cancer. I found the papers where people use 3D scaffolds to cultivate MCF7 cells and after the cultivation cells show the increased invasiveness. So during the cultivation cells somehow change. Perhaps the surface markers are involved, perhaps something else.
When dealing with the patients I must be sure to get the same cells after cultivation that were in the patient, or very close to the initial ones. I want to build a model for cultivation: to use say the same MCF7 to develop the cultivating protocol and then to test it on real patients. It`s easy to build the input and output control on the MCF7, but what changes should I look for?

These kinds of questions confuse me. It's fine to ask, and we're happy to help if we can, please don't get me wrong. Unless research has changed drastically since I was doing it, you should be doing this in a lab where there should be written protocols for everything you do, like, everything. If you're in a relatively new field and you're developing a protocol, you should be consulting experts in the field. There are tons of literature on breast cancer research. What are your circumstances?

What are CTCs? Please do not use this type of abbreviation in the title of a question, and define it on first use in the main body.

Great question. CTC = circulating tumor cell. It's a biomarker for denoting metastatic cancer. There could be a cell biology expert in around.

@anongoodnurse, Im in "relatively new field" situation. Ive looked through quite a lot of papers on ... circulating tumor cells ... cultivation, the main idea of them is: "we`ve cultivated something, something has grown and we conduct our experiments on this "something"". We have markers and probably gene changes in cells that go to different fields of body. F.e. here (yup, the article is 10 y.o. bu still) they tried to grow breast-cancer-to-bone metastasis. 2 cycles of "metastasing" MCF7 into the bone and they have more aggressive cells...

And if we face the same case in the patient... Cells f.e. went from breast to bone, from bone to liver... And we have a coctail of different cancer cells in the blood... And how to look at them?

@Hedgehog - Sorry I can't help. It's been decades since I did research (carcinogenesis/skin cancer); if I were in your place, I'd be contacting the main author of that paper and asking questions, and to ask if they knew of others who were working with same. There is a site in this network, Academia.SE, which might be able to guide you better than this one. Have a look at the site to see if your question (about how to find/contact others in your field) would fit. I hope you get some good ideas sometime soon.
